# How to convert a highcharts Pie chart to HTML/Table on drilldown

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Is there any way to convert a pie chart to an HTML table?
I have seen this jQuery plugin http://highcharttable.org/ that converts HTML table to a chart, but I want exactly opposite of this.

Preferably I would like to do this on clicking a piece of pie chart to see the data records only behind that part.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the charting library you use. Usually the data is fed into a chart as an object or an array of values or JSON. I'd suggest using this initial data to create your table dynamically.

Comment: I am using highcharts. Off-course that is the one option to do it yourself with actual data. But I would like to know if Highcharts has any built-in feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by handling the click event bound to the chart.

Here's the sample code of the handler:

```
var createTable = function($chart) {

    console.log("$series = %o", $chart);

    // remove the existing table
    $('#here_table table').remove();

    // create a table object
    var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('chart-table');

    // iterate the series object, create rows and columnts
    $.each($chart.series.data, function( index, value ) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('chart-row');
        var col1 = $('<td></td>').text(value.name).appendTo(row);
        var col2 = $('<td></td>').text(value.percentage).appendTo(row);

        // mark the row of the clicked sector
        if ($chart.name == value.name)
            row.addClass('selected');

        table.append(row);
    });

    // insert the table into DOM
    $('#here_table').append(table);
};
```

Full example is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/mhz7ffbo/1/)

Also, check this: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table